# SQL/PHP where clause changes depending on row id

Tags: php, sql, where-clause

I wish to select all rows depending on the where value, which changes with each row. The best way to explain it would be like this...

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `time` < $array[ ROW ID ][ time ]
```

Hence, the value of the where clause will change depending on the row itself

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sub query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `time` < (
  SELECT `time` FROM `table` WHERE `id` = ROW_ID
);
```

The sub query selects `time` from the row with id `ROW_ID` and after that the main query compares the result to `time` properties of the other records in the table.

You play around with the query at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbdd0/2)

---

The question was a little bit hard to get.. I think now (after discussion) this is what you want:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `time` < ' . $array['ROW_ID']['time'];
```

Comment: that would work if the data came off the database, I however want it too come from my php array. I need ID to use as a key for the array...